# Every word underlined with red in TexWorks

Tags: editors, texworks, spelling, dictionaries

The title really says it all.

I have tried reinstalling the dictionaries in the `dictionaries` subfolder under the `TexWorks` folder, but to no avail.

If I open `TexWorks`, go to `Edit -> Spelling` and choose `None`, the red lines all disappear (as one might expect). If I then, on the other hand, choose `English - United Kingdom (en_GB)` (the language I am writing in), then *every single word* in the document becomes underlined.

This is not ideal, as I really do want a spell checker.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: This depends on the OS, in Linux you should have some like `en_GB.dic` and `en_GB.aff` in `/usr/share/hunspell/` (and of course, have hunspell installed).

Comment: @Fran I use MikTeX on Windows 10. Is hunspell something I should install separately? Everything I find seems to be on the dodgy side of the internet.

Comment: yes, hunspell is a spell checker program that is used by LibreOffice, OpenOffice, Firefox,  Thunderbird, Chrome, etc. It is based  in myspell so you can use the same dictionaries.